# Can't understand the behaviour of CUDA kernel launch

Tags: c++, cuda

```
#include "utils.h"

__global__
void rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4* const rgbaImage,
                       unsigned char* const greyImage,
                       int numRows, int numCols)
{
  for (size_t r = 0; r < numRows; ++r) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < numCols; ++c) {
      uchar4 rgba = rgbaImage[r * numCols + c];
      float channelSum = 0.299f * rgba.x + 0.587f * rgba.y + 0.114f * rgba.z;
      greyImage[r * numCols + c] = channelSum;
    }
  }
}

void your_rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4 * const h_rgbaImage, uchar4 * const d_rgbaImage,
                            unsigned char* const d_greyImage, size_t numRows, size_t numCols)
{
  const dim3 blockSize(1, 1, 1);  //TODO
  const dim3 gridSize( 1, 1, 1);  //TODO
  rgba_to_greyscale<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

}
```

This is the code used for converting a color image to grayscale. I am working on this assignment for a course and have got these results after `completing it`.

```
A.
blockSize = (1, 1, 1)
gridSize = (1, 1, 1)
Your code ran in: 34.772705 msecs.

B.
blockSize = (numCols, 1, 1)
gridSize = (numRows, 1, 1)
Your code ran in: 1821.326416 msecs.

C.
blockSize = (numRows, 1, 1)
gridSize = (numCols, 1, 1)
Your code ran in: 1695.917480 msecs.

D.
blockSize = (1024, 1, 1)
gridSize = (170, 1, 1) [the image size is : r=313, c=557, blockSize*gridSize ~= r*c]
Your code ran in: 1709.109863 msecs.
```

I have tried a few more combinations but none got better performance than A. I got close with just a few ns of difference on increasing blocksize and gridsize by small values.
Ex:

```
blockSize = (10, 1, 1)
gridSize = (10, 1, 1)
Your code ran in: 34.835167 msecs.
```

I dont understand why higher numbers dont get better performance and instead lead to worse performance. Also, it seems that increasing blocksize is better than gridsize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculate all the pixels in every thread you launch, i.e. the kernel is completely serial. Using more blocks or larger blocks is just repeating  calculations.  In the latter case, why not move the for loop out of the kernel and have each thread calculate one pixel?